# c.s.a of a hemisphere

Tags: spherical-geometry

Here is a question which I would like to understand. I want to know

How to prove that c.s.a of a hemisphere is $2\pi r^2$ ?
[image]

I'm a 10th CLASS average student,so please keep it simple.

Thank you....

Comment: c.s.a. = Confederate States of America?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson curved surface area

Comment: Thanks. How is that different from just plain old surface area?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it does not include the plane surface area $\pi r^2$

Comment: OK. There is no fully rigorous way to get that formula without using Calculus (or at any rate, some limit calculation). Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Area to see what you're up against. You might enjoy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RrjbeuoNOA which is a video showing how Archimedes did it.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106865/how-did-archimedes-find-the-surface-area-of-a-sphere --- in fact, type Archimedes area of a sphere into Google and lots of pages come up.

Comment: Still with us, Shivam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that C.S.A of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$. Therefore C.S.A of hemisphere is $2\pi r^2$.

Comment: How is csa of  a sphere $4\pi r^2$, i need a proff.

Comment: @ShivamGautam are u comfortable with integration

Comment: this might help [mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/QQ.09.99/wilkie1.html](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/QQ.09.99/wilkie1.html)